# A Rhymey Rileyo

Tags: riddle, word

> My start suggests I’m made of dough
>
> My suffix is one, so
>
> Right in between, one can be seen
>
> And I have caused a flow

Any idea who I might be?

A hint for third and second clue:

> To get them both resolved 
>  They should be taken literally 
>  No islands are involved

Another hint for you:

> Sounds like or tricks I must dismiss, need for a whiz to settle this? Let suffix be what suffix is

One more to serve as cue:

> "so" hints at a link, correct I think, another word's truly in sync

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> Me, Riley

My start suggests I'm made of dough

> Ri as in rye bread

My suffix is one

> "ey" is itself a suffix in general.

Right in between, one can be seen

> The infix "ile" is also a suffix in general.

And I have caused a flow

> Of these kinds of riddles

Comment: The answer is true, I had some different thoughts about that third and second clue...

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: Not really, no tries have been bad, just a little far-fetched, happy to drop in a hint if required

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you were going for. Feel free to add a hint.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm getting closer. Still not entirely sure about the second clue

Comment: Just heeding @Rubio's advice here.. since you have the right answer but not the intended clues, rot13("Zl fhssvk vf bar" fubhyq or gnxra va n yvgreny frafr, jung qbrf gung znxr gur nyernql pbeerpg "fhssvk" bs lbhe anzr? naq jung qbrf gung znxr gur jbeq "bar" va gur arkg fragrapr?)

Comment: I appreciate you trying to hint me in the right direction, but I still have no idea about the second line. How is "ey" one? Is it in another language or something?

Comment: Hehe, no, maybe it's due to the fact that I'm a non-native English speaker, but rot13(zl fhssvk vf bar, fb gura bar zhfg or n ... va gur yvgreny frafr)

Comment: Could it be that rot13("rl", nf va "rlr", vf frrvat gur "y" va gur zvqqyr?)

Comment: Nope, it has to do with rot13(jung "rl" (s)npghnyyl/yvgrenyyl vf, nyy ol vgfrys), but I'm starting to get the feeling the way that sentence is trying to convey the message might really not be a proper English way to do so, if so please enlighten me :)

Comment: Are you trying to say that rot13(rl vf vgfrys n fhssvk va trareny?) If you suspect that what you're trying to convey has not been expressed correctly in English, then it might be time to just say what you intended.

Comment: Yep but now you got it, and the next sentence should make sense too..

Comment: I'm sorry but I think the second line was very poorly worded, and doesn't literally mean what you think it means. Since you've already used "one" in a very unclear way in the second line, I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "one" in the third line.

Comment: Ok, will try to somehow learn how that sentence doesn't mean what I think it means.. but yes indeed I meant that rot13(rl vf vgfrys n fhssvk va trareny?) and therefore, right in between rot13(fbzrguvat ryfr, juvpu vf nyfb vgfrys n fhssvk, pna or frra)...

Comment: Now is it that rot13(orgjrra ev naq rl vf "y", juvpu vf n fhssvk?)

Comment: Nope, but rot13(vyr) is..

Comment: Alright, I updated my answer. I appreciate your effort to make a good riddle, but the English really doesn't indicate what you were going for.

Comment: Yep, you've got the tick, I live and learn :) thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is

> The Bunea River

My start suggests I’m made of dough

> A "bun" is a bread roll, made of dough

My suffix is one, so

> "a" is indicative of "one"

Right in between, one can be seen

> "une" is French for "one"

And I have caused a flow

> As noted, there exists the Bunea River

Comment: +1 from me, I didn't know about the Bunea river, but it does fit quite nicely! Not what I was thinking though. Riley actually got the answer right already, it's just some of the clue explanations that don't really make sense yet which is holding me off to give him the tick.

Answer (score 1):

Because the rest of the riddle is explained by  him, I'm not going to explain the whole riddle just the part Riley missed...

> I think (based on punctuation) that the two lines are the same just split apart so,

My suffix is one, so
Right in between, one can be seen

> Because of that specific suffix (ley) it makes his name have a 1 (l) in the middle of his name. (Whether a lower case L is a roman numeral one or just a sloppily written one I don't Know.) I'm taking the clues literally like the hint suggests.

Comment: I like it at lot, but not what I had in mind, I have dropped another hint.